# Wordpress : restrict all URLs but /

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I need a simple thing on a Wordpress project : **I want only the front page ('/') to be visible/accessible by users / robots.**

**What's the better way to achieve this ?** htaccess / robots.txt ?

As I said, it seems really simple, but I can't find the best way to do that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `wp_safe_redirect()`:

```
add_action( 'get_header', 'so26754591_redirect', 0 );
function so26754591_redirect()
{
    if( is_front_page() )
        return;

    wp_safe_redirect( home_url( '/' ) );
    exit;
}
```

This assumes your theme has a `front-page.php` template. Otherwise use the `is_home()` conditional. `wp_safe_redirect()` accept an optional second parameter, `$status`, e.g. `301` or `302`.

Comment: I try that and this is why I chose this solution : I chose not to bother with htaccess because I think this behavior is only related to the theme, not to the whole website. So this is the right thing to do I IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this rule as very first rule in your .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule !^(index\.php)?$ - [F,NC]
```

Comment: I'll need a bit a explanation about this : what does it do litterally ?

Comment: Sure. It will return forbidden (https status: 403) to any URL request that is not root `/` OR `index.php`. `!^(index\.php)?$` is used for negation of the pattern which is `^(index\.php)?$` that matches `index.php` or nothing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommending using a `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: As I'll need to deploy it on 2 servers at least, I'm looking for a relative url (if it's possible).